# Kubernetes metric or command to show liveness delay time (app startup time)

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring

HTTP Kubernetes liveness and readiness checks are [configured as per the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/).

The `initialDelaySeconds` field tells the kubelet how long it should wait before performing the first liveness / readiness probe.

In [this official blog article by a Google Developer Advocate](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-setting-up-health-checks-with-readiness-and-liveness-probes) it says:

> I recommend using the p99 startup time as the `initialDelaySeconds`, or just take the average startup time and add a buffer. As your app's startup time gets faster or slower, make sure you update this number.

... possibly implying that monitoring of your app's startup time is a reasonably trivial or built-in kubernetes function!?

- Is there a metric available in Kubernetes for container or pod startup time (time between either "pending" or "running" to the time the liveness check succeeds)?
- If there is no existing metric, is there any `kubectl` command, other API or plugin, that can be used to determine the equivalent information?

---

#### Clarify:

My environment uses Scala / Finagle, which seems to need a significant amount of time to start and warm-up (60-300 seconds depending on resource limits), so accuracy to within a few seconds is fine. There is no need for the solution to be second/millisecond accurate.

---

#### Small progress update:

I found that the `kubectl` command below can be used to show the time between the [completion of the initialization phase, and the pod being ready to serve requests](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-conditions). However, the `Ready` time here would already include `initialDelaySeconds`, rather than indicating the earliest time the pod was actually able to serve. Also, this gives overall times for the pod, but no information about specific containers.

```
kubectl get pod $POD_NAME -o 'go-template=
{{range .status.conditions}}
  {{if and (or (eq .type "Initialized") (eq .type "Ready")) (eq .status "True")}}
    {{printf "%s ==> %s\n" .type .lastTransitionTime }}
  {{end}}
{{end}}'
```

output:

```
Initialized ==> 2019-05-28T01:47:35Z
Ready ==> 2019-05-28T01:50:24Z
```

Comment: Could you indicate whether you solved the issue?